# Issue using jackson to parse JSON containing variable that equals the "final" keyword in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson to parse json files to java objects.
This requires me to create java objects matching the json files. However currently I have a json file looking like this:

```
{
  "name": "myName",
  "final": "whatever"
}
```

Normally I would create a matching class in java:

```
class MyClass {
    String name;
    String final;
}
```

However the problem here is that 'final' is a java keyword and can't be used as a Java variable name. What would be the best way to solve this (trying to avoid manual parsing as the above is just a simplified version of the real situation).

Comment: call your variable inside class whatever you want and add `@JsonProperty("final") `above it.

Comment: Great that works, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation to tell jackson how to serialize/deserialize your custom fields. `final` is a special keyword in Java so you can use this annotation and name field whatever is valid :

```
class MyClass {

    String name;

    @JsonProperty("final")
    String someName;

}
```